# How do I edit a dictionary as many times as needed through two functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope

I have this code for Python:

```
def additems():
    items = {}
    add = input("What would you like to add?")
    value = input("What value would you like to assign?")
    items[add] = value
    return items

def resume():
    decision = input("would you like to continue?")
    if decision == "Y":
        main()
    else:
       print("Exiting...")

def main():
    items = additems()
    print(items)
    resume()

main()
```

The objective is to be able to edit "items" as many times as I want while always returning the updated dictionary back to main. But, as it stands, I can only edit the dictionary once inside the function "additems" and then it resets when "main" is run. I don't want the dictionary to reset when main is run, I always want it to print the updated "items" dictionary. So instead of:

"What would you like to add?"
 - G
"What value would you like to assign?"
 - 3
"{'G': '3'}"
"Would you like to continue?"
 - Y 
"What would you like to add?"
 - J
"What value would you like to assign?"
 - 4
"{'J': '4'}" (only the most recent addition to the dictionary is printed)

... Which is what the code currently does, I want it to be able to do:

"What would you like to add?"
 - G
"What value would you like to assign?"
 - 3
"{'G': '3'}"
"Would you like to continue?"
 - Y 
"What would you like to add?"
 - J
"What value would you like to assign?"
 - 4
"{'G': '3', 'J': '4'}" (both additions are printed)

... and to be able to do this as long as I provide an input of Y, meaning I am able to continue.

If you haven't already guessed, I am new to both Stack and to Python, but help would be appreciated. Thus, when I mean help, I mean help in the context of one who is new to Python and programming in general, not help to one with experience. Just answer as if you were talking to a 5 year old and save us all the trouble.

Comment: Make `items` a global(as @AChampion said 'blah!') instead and remove the definition and `return` from `additems` then just call `additems` from `main` instead of assigning

Comment: Because you are recursing down the call stack you will need to pass the dict with it or create a global dictionary (not recommended if you can avoid it - and you can avoid it!). Alternatively, implement this iteratively.

Comment: Thanks to both @Nick A  for your swiftly given advice! I never thought to make the dictionary a global, and I have done so and it works (:D), however ideally I store it in a function somewhere instead of the alternative. Thus my next question is of course: how do I go about achieving this? Preferably answered in a way that *sigh* my inept mind can understand.

Comment: In that case, I suggest you define items in your main, then pass it as a parameter to getitems, there you can update it and return it (as opposed to making a new empty items dictionary each call), and have a think about your program structure so that you arent using recursion (calling main from resume). Hint: `while` loop

Answer (score 1):

As @AChampion noted you don't need recursion, just pass `items` from `main` function to `additems`.

Since [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) objects are mutable we don't need to pass and return them, just mutate in case of need.

We can replace recursion with infinite loop like

```
def additems(items):
    add = input("What would you like to add?\n")
    value = input("What value would you like to assign?\n")
    items[add] = value


def main():
    items = {}
    while True:
        additems(items)
        print(items)
        decision = input("would you like to continue?\n")
        if decision != "Y":
            print("Exiting...")
            return


main()
```

I've added newline characters `'\n'` to the end of each question to make it simpler for user to interact, if you don't need them – feel free to remove.